# Splunk DB Input not getting indexed

Tags: database, splunk

So just messing around with Splunk and DBConnect 2.04 on my local machine. I have a postgres DB on it as well, and have set up a DB Input in splunk, everything seems to check out, but after saving this connection, nothing ever appears in my index.

Is there something else that needs to be done before the connection is actually used? I can see in the DBX log that it's regularly running py_dbinput and reporting success, but again, nothing in the index... What can I be missing here?

Obviously, I do have a couple of rows of data in the table that I can see using the query listed.

I want to get this

```
1;"Something";"2015-08-25 16:58:40.927329+02"
2;"Something else";"2015-08-25 16:58:47.357958+02"
```

into the Splunk index using this query:

```
SELECT id, message, to_char(message_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') FROM "messagelog"
```

Comment: Can u provide more details on how you configured? Are you indexing an entire table or using a custom select query?

Comment: I guess what I am after is that once I configure the DB Input and point it at an index, do I need to do anything more for Splunk to start processing events from that source?

Answer (score 0):

Dumbing down the timestamp options (from trying to get a PGSQL timestamp using to_char to just using the index time as the timestamp worked...